# rounding up the python list values before saving to DB

Tags: python, rounding

I'm saving the monthly forecasted values in postgesDB matching with actual result using python
eg monthly forecasted values [10.5, 20.6, 30.8, 5.4, 0, 1, 1.4, 2.2] which sums 71.9 and actual result 65

my solution is to get a rescale factor by dividing actual to forecasted sum 65 / 71.9 = 0.904 and multiply that to all values in forecasted values now new list will be [9.492, 18.622, 27.843, 4.881, 0, 0.904, 1.265, 1.988] which sums to 64.995 and rounded to 65 the actual value, but now I was asked to forecasted values can only be integers, what is the best way to refactor the list to have the forecasted values as only "positive integers" and be close to actual result by +-1. I tried rounding the list values after refactor but for list large records the difference to actual value is more that 100

Comment: One option: multiply the values by some power of 10 and store that as an integer. Ex `9.492 * 1000 = 9492`. Then when retrieving from the database, divide by same value.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = []
forecast = [10.5, 20.6, 30.8, 5.4, 0, 1, 1.4, 2.2]
actual_result = 65
rounded_list = [round(number) for number in forecast if number >= 0]

percentage = actual_result / sum(rounded_list)

for number in rounded_list:
     results.append(number * percentage)
```

Print list:

```
[9.154929577464788, 19.225352112676056, 28.380281690140844, 4.577464788732394, 0.0, 0.9154929577464789, 0.9154929577464789, 1.8309859154929577]
```

Print sum list:

```
65.0
```

If you want to be very precise and the forecast list should only be integer:

```
results = []
forecast = [10.5, 20.6, 30.8, 5.4, 0, 1, 1.4, 2.2]
actual_result = 65
rounded_list = [number * 10 for number in forecast if number >= 0]

percentage = 65 * 10 / sum(rounded_list)

for number in rounded_list:
    results.append(number * percentage / 10)
```

Print list:

```
[9.492350486787204, 18.6230876216968, 27.8442280945758, 4.881780250347704, 0.0, 0.9040333796940194, 1.265646731571627, 1.9888734353268425]
```

Print list sum:

```
65.0
```

Comment: [10, 21, 31, 5, 0, 1, 1, 2] sum 71 but it needs to be close to actual result 65 by _+ 1

Comment: If you know how many maximum decimal places your data have, you can multiply your list by the factor, if you multiply your other result by the same factor and divide again you get an exact percentage number. This would be a possibility

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Higs but in my case I wanted the DB to have integers and the need code to make the rescaling as the data will be used by different API calls there should be one source of truth

Comment: Ok, with larger amounts of data it is inevitable that you get large deviations. A last option that would occur to me would be that you store the numbers that are omitted in the rounding in a variable and by a formula your other numbers are calculated.

Comment: Why, should the integer be calculated out of it?